# Convert a CFStringRef to a C string?

Tags: objective-c, c, cfstring

Hello lovely computer people:

I would like to convert the following CFStringRef into a CString. Any idea how?

```
recordFilePath = (CFStringRef)[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordedFile.wav"];
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT 1

DarkDust answer seems to come close, but I'm still getting an error (see comment). Any help?

Comment: This is objective-c, right?  Tag should be fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a `CFStringRef` can be toll-free casted to `NSString`, you can simply do:

```
myCString = [(NSString *)myCFStringRef UTF8String];
```

or in your case:

```
myCString = [[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordedFile.wav"] UTF8String];
```

Comment: hmmmmm... I'm not sure if I'm missing something here. Isn't that an NSString? I'm looking for a c string. Like char newString [] =.

Comment: That's what the `UTF8String` method gives you, a null-terminated c-string.

Comment: I'm getting 'myCString is not declared in this scope' :(

Comment: @Eric Brotto: It's just a placeholder variable name.

Comment: Got it! I was missing const char * myCString. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 14):

A straightforward solution:

```
CFStringGetCString(myCFStringRef, myCStringPointer, mySize, myEncoding);
```

Checkout this function:

```
Boolean CFStringGetCString (
   CFStringRef theString,
   char *buffer,
   CFIndex bufferSize,
   CFStringEncoding encoding
);
```